# Do I define new models if they already exist in db?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I am new to Django. I am trying to write a code, which takes data from a database and shows it in a website. My question is, if the data already exist in the database and I only want to get them, do I need to define new models in the models.py?

Comment: Yes, you should still create models if you want to use Django's ORM. There are a few things you should take into account so that you don't accidentally modify the database structure though. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/legacy-databases/) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The Django documentation is nice but sometimes for someone like me, who is not very experienced can be overwhelming. Thank you again :-)